# query for counting rows in sql with filters in ms access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on a simple read write database with design form.
I used this query for counting all rows
`SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblData`

Now I can't get to count the rows when I am adding a filter. I tried various queries, some instructions here, but I can't decode it and make it vba. I need to find all ***pending*** status of ***338559***

[image]

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim query As String
Dim i As Integer

query = "SELECT COUNT Status = 'Pending' FROM tblData WHERE UID = 338559"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(query)

For i = 0 To recordCountOfTheItem
    'code to display it to listbox
Next i
```

Thank you for some assistance coders :)

Comment: If your actual goal is to fill a listbox from a query (filtered table), then you don't need the count at all. Is this the case? (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: yep, the goal is to fill that listbox with the filtered table. should I ask another for that? Well the solution would be to loop through the filtered table so I need the count - in which case the query is not working, so that's what I asked here. But good point on that link :D I probably just added the whole problem so that you can see where Im coming from..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use that request :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tblData
WHERE UID = 338559
  AND Status = 'Pending';
```

Comment: this is the right query, though it was solved by @arulkumar by reminding me of what type the `UID` is, I have put it to text that's why the `where clause` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by `CASE` statement, if the condition is satisfies set as 1 and if not satisfies set as NULL. This will work for **MySQL**

When Count it won't consider the null values, so you will get valid count for your filter

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'Pending' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
FROM tblData WHERE UID = 338559
```

For VBA Access 2007

```
SELECT COUNT(IIF(Status = 'Pending', 1, NULL))
FROM tblData WHERE UID = 338559
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, but is this sql accepted for vba access 2007? I get syntax error (missing operator) in that query. Also ebahi's answer, gets me data mismatch/syntax error too.

Comment: run time error 3464 - data type mismatch in criteria expression. I also tried this one `select count (*) from tblData where UID = 338559` same error. But when I dont add the `where clause` it does push through

Comment: What is the data type of `UID`? Is INT or VARCHAR ?

Comment: I don't know where to check, I think that is only for mySQL format database. I only use access, and the `UID` field is set to short text/text, there's no indication if its int or varchar, but I assume its varchar.

Comment: @AdorableVB : Then you can use the WHERE clause as `WHERE UID = '338559'`

Comment: Yeah, i totally forgot about that. goodlord. :D I just tried it after commenting. I used `rs.RecordCount`, it displays 1. Is that the right code to get the count?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112506/discussion-between-arulkumar-and-adorablevb).

Comment: @AdorableVB Acces does not calculate the `rs.recordCount` unless forced to. you can cheat it by doing `rs.MoveLast` and then `rs.moveFirst`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to count, just loop:

```
query = "SELECT COUNT Status = 'Pending' FROM tblData WHERE UID = 338559"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(query)

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    While rs.EOF = False
        'code to display it to listbox
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record: To fill a listbox with data from a query, you need neither `Count()` nor VBA at all.

Just set the listbox `RowSource` to the query, e.g.

```sql
SELECT <whichever fields you want to display> FROM tblData
WHERE UID = '338559' AND Status = 'Pending';
```